# Wrong Mapping using FluentNHibernate NHibernate 3.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I get error when I working with "FluentNHibernate". Similar file in .xml working correct but I would like to use "FluentNHibernate" is much more easier. Do you know where I made mistake? and how to fix this issue?

**Copy Exception**

```
NHibernate.MappingException was unhandled by user code
  Message=No persister for: TreningToWork.Models.Person
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName, Object obj)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
       at NHibernateTutorial.PersonRepository.Add(Person newPerson) in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\Repository\PersonRepository.cs:line 15
       at TreningToWork.Controllers.ShowDataController.Index() in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\Controllers\ShowDataController.cs:line 21
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

Exception(more details):

[image]

Exception(more details):

[image]

FluentNHibernate (making this same as .xml)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using FluentNHibernate.Automapping;
using FluentNHibernate.Automapping.Alterations;

namespace TreningToWork.Models
{
    public class Person 
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Surname { get; set; }
    }
    public class PersonMappingAltertation : IAutoMappingOverride<Person>
    {
        public void Override(AutoMapping<Person> mapping)
        {
            mapping.Table("Person");
            mapping.Id(x => x.Id, "Id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
            mapping.Map(x=> x.Name, "Name").Column("Name").Not.Nullable();
            mapping.Map(x => x.Surname, "Surname").Column("Surname").Not.Nullable();
        }
    }
}
```

Person Helper

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using TreningToWork.Models;

namespace TreningToWork.ModelsHelper
{
    public class PersonHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    var configuration = new Configuration();
                    configuration.Configure();
                    configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Person).Assembly);
                    _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }
}
```

Person Repository

```
using NHibernate;
using TreningToWork.Models;
using TreningToWork.ModelsHelper;

namespace NHibernateTutorial
{
    public class PersonRepository
    {
        public void Add(Person newPerson)
        {
            using (ISession session = PersonHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(newPerson);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

        public Person GetPersonByName(string name)
        {
            using (ISession session = PersonHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                var result = session.QueryOver<Person>().Where(x => x.Name == name).SingleOrDefault();
                return result ?? new Person();
            }
        }

        public void Update(Person newPerson)
        {
            using (ISession session = PersonHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Update(newPerson);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Delete(Person newPerson)
        {
            using (ISession session = PersonHelper.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Delete(newPerson);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Edited file Error**

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Data Source
  Source=System.Data
  ParamName=Data Source
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_DataSource(String value)
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder.Create()
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.PersistenceConfiguration`2.CreateProperties()
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.PersistenceConfiguration`2.ConfigureProperties(Configuration nhibernateConfig)
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.Database(IPersistenceConfigurer config)
       at TreningToWork.ModelsHelper.PersonHelper.get_SessionFactory() in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\ModelsHelper\PersonHelper.cs:line 20
       at TreningToWork.ModelsHelper.PersonHelper.OpenSession() in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\ModelsHelper\PersonHelper.cs:line 40
       at NHibernateTutorial.PersonRepository.Add(Person newPerson) in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\Repository\PersonRepository.cs:line 11
       at TreningToWork.Controllers.ShowDataController.Index() in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\Controllers\ShowDataController.cs:line 21
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

**My changed Factory**

```
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;
using TreningToWork.Models;

namespace TreningToWork.ModelsHelper
{
    public class PersonHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get
            {
                if (_sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(c => c
                    .FromAppSetting("rafalConnectionString"))
                        //<%$ ConnectionStrings:rafalConnectionString %>
                    .ShowSql())
                    .Mappings(m => m
                    .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Person>())
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
                    // var configuration = new Configuration();
                    // configuration.Configure();
                    // configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Person).Assembly);
                    // _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }
}
```

Really, I have got problem with configure. I add my project to this post. Tell me where I made mistake and how to fix this issue. I didn`t find good example for this and probably this project will go to youtube when will be finished for future. For other users.

IF you understand all files in this post you don`t have to upload my project.

Important files :

Controller -> there is controller
Models, ModelsHelper, Repository and View. If you open website my softweare have to put to database new table and data there. Now I have got problem with this. When I use .xml files everything working correct but I would like to use "FluentNHibernate" and this is a problem.

File: [My project download praca.zip](http://www.sendspace.pl/file/b010fb8d696dd5ebcfcd34b)

Next error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Data Source
  Source=System.Data
  ParamName=Data Source
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_DataSource(String value)
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder.Create()
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.PersistenceConfiguration`2.CreateProperties()
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.PersistenceConfiguration`2.ConfigureProperties(Configuration nhibernateConfig)
       at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.Database(IPersistenceConfigurer config)
       at TreningToWork.ModelsHelper.PersonHelper.get_SessionFactory() in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\ModelsHelper\PersonHelper.cs:line 21
       at TreningToWork.ModelsHelper.PersonHelper.OpenSession() in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\ModelsHelper\PersonHelper.cs:line 50
       at NHibernateTutorial.PersonRepository.Add(Person newPerson) in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\Repository\PersonRepository.cs:line 11
       at TreningToWork.Controllers.ShowDataController.Index() in D:\praca\TreningToWork\TreningToWork\Controllers\ShowDataController.cs:line 21
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Please show the creation of your session factory.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth now I added all files to post

Comment: You didn't configure any auto-mapping, yet you are using an auto-mapping override. You need to fix your configuration. Start [here](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started) for a general introduction to Fluent NHibernate. And continue [here](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration) for an explanation on how to configure it.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I will try but it's difficult to find good way which can be useful for my example.

Comment: No, it's not difficult. The links I gave you contain everything you need to know. You just have to *read* them.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - Can you look into my edit post?

Comment: Really, you need to read the links I gave you. You are not configuring your session factory for auto-mapping. But I am not going to repeat it for you, it is crystal-clear in the Fluent NH wiki.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Do you know good video tutorial for FluentNHibernate.Automapping

Comment: No. Why don't you just *read* the wiki? What's the problem with that?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I read as you can see on my edited post and I made "ISessionFactory" but doesn`t work correct.

Comment: Don't just fast-read it. Take your time to read and understand. You are configuring your factory for *fluent mapping* but you are using an *auto-mapping* override.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I`m sorry I asking you a lot of times but really I would like to configure this correct. I changed my post (Edited file Error) and (My changed Factory) Can you look it?

Comment: Use `m.AutoMappings.Add`. You don't read what I write or what the wiki explains. I give up and am out of here. This is my last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems with your project were too numerous to list. I made many changes (mainly deleted unnecessary code), got it to work and uploaded it to http://www.sendspace.pl/en/file/8f7f2ebf8fabf912800d64c.

The key change was using Ninject dependency injection framework to create the session factory as a singleton and the session per request.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Your project is excellent example. My question is: Can you prepare good youtube tutorial for other users using this project? or if you have not time I can do it, but I prefere your video tutorial with explenation with similar title to this post and of course link in this post to your tutorial.

Comment: Link to sendspace does not exist? any chance you can repost somewhere e.g. GIST

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your background, working with NH and FNH can be very confusing at first.

But if you replace this line:

```
.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Person>())
```

with this line:

```
.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Person>())
```

I believe this will solve your problem, or at least point you in the right direction.

Also, you should be able to eliminate your PersonMappingAltertation override - it is not needed - such a simple entity should automap just fine.

Go the [FNH Wiki Auto mapping page](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping) for a good overview of Automapping.

This will also link to a [sample project](http://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/tree/master/src/Examples.FirstAutomappedProject), which I found was the best way to get started.

Comment: I have got two problems first I using 2012 database and I don`t know how to configure for FluentNHibernate another (Next error) this is topic of error in my post which I get one minute ago.